# Email Terminal Shortcut

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I need to change this VBA code for class. I'm looking at this tutorial http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/sending_personalized_email_from_excel/ and instead of Outlook, I want to use Apple Mail stmp["mailto:"] functions directly from excel. I have the subject and message portion down, but all I want to know if I can run this script directly from terminal if we save this properly? And also can you annotate where I need to make specific changes pertaining to my email.

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

    Sub SendEMail()
    Dim Email As String, Subj As String
    Dim Msg As String, URL As String
    Dim r As Integer, x As Double
    For r = 2 To 4 'data in rows 2-4
    '       Get the email address
        Email = Cells(r, 2)

    '       Message subject
        Subj = "Your Annual Bonus"

    '       Compose the message
        Msg = ""
        Msg = Msg & "Dear " & Cells(r, 1) & "," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        Msg = Msg & "I am pleased to inform you that your annual bonus is "

        Msg = Msg & Cells(r, 3).Text & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        Msg = Msg & "William Rose" & vbCrLf
        Msg = Msg & "President"

    '       Replace spaces with %20 (hex)
        Subj = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Subj, " ", "%20")
        Msg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Msg, " ", "%20")

    '       Replace carriage returns with %0D%0A (hex)
        Msg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Msg, vbCrLf, "%0D%0A")        
    '       Create the URL
        URL = "mailto:" & Email & "?subject=" & Subj & "&body=" & Msg        

    '       Execute the URL (start the email client)
        ShellExecute 0&, vbNullString, URL, vbNullString, vbNullString, vbNormalFocus

    '       Wait two seconds before sending keystrokes
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Application.SendKeys "%s"
    Next r
    End Sub
```

Comment: I should point out StackOverflow is not the place to get people to do your homework for you...

Comment: ...also VBA <> VB.NET

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, you can save a VBA application as a .vbs file and run it from the command prompt or from Windows Explorer. There might be errors, if you have Excel specific functions, or if the VB versions aren't the same, but in general it will run.